# How to efficiently initialize many DataFrames with the same index name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several pandas `DataFrame` objects. I want all of them to have the same index name. For example, I could do it this way:

```py
df1=pd.DataFrame()
df2=pd.DataFrame()
df3=pd.DataFrame()
df1.index.name = 'Hours'
df2.index.name = 'Hours'
df3.index.name = 'Hours'
```

But what if I have a large number of `DataFrame` objects? How could I do this at once for all the different objects?

Comment: Are  you dataframes in sort of collection (list/dictionary) or named in a unique way?

Comment: a list/dict comprehension should suffice

Answer (score 0):

The [`DataFrame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) initializer accepts an `index` argument, so you could do something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

dataframes = []

for _ in range(100):
    dataframes.append(pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index([1, 2], name='Hours')))
```

This could also be written as a list comprehension:

```py
dataframes = [pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index([1, 2], name='Hours')) for _ in range(100)]
```

See also [`pandas.Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.html).